# How to set up ssl in tomcat?

Tags: tomcat6

I am trying to setup ssl in tomcat.

I have googled many websites, some told to add keystore file path in the connector tag in server.xml file. and sone not.

I followed many tutorial, but while typing the url, it is keep on loading, and it could not catch the application.

Please teach me how to set up https site in tomcat.
Thanks

Comment: when you say "it is keep on loading" that could mean a few things. For instance you might be accessing this on the wrong port or maybe the connector just isn't working. Could you please post the connector tag from your server.xml? Also have a look in your log files and see if there is some error messages there.

Comment: You don't need to google any websites. You just need to follow the directions at the [*Tomcat* website](http://tomcat.apache.org).

Answer (score 2):

I recommend following the official documentation on the subject: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html

This has worked for me in the past.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](http://techtracer.com/2007/09/12/setting-up-ssl-on-tomcat-in-3-easy-steps/) as a start

and the document mentionned by [bernard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601866/how-to-set-up-ssl-in-tomcat/3602053#3602053) is well enough for you.

Answer (score -1):

You can configure SSL by using JSSE or APR Implementation.
I'm mentioning steps to configure SSL with APR Implementation

First install APR native Library

```
cd /root
wget http://www.eu.apache.org/dist/apr/apr-1.5.2.tar.gz
tar -xzvf apr-1.5.2.tar.gz
cd apr-1.5.2
./configure && make && make install
```

Install Tomcat Native Library

```
cd TOMCATPATH/bin/           #There should be tomcat native library tar
tar -xzvf tomcat-native.tar.gz
cd tomcat-native-1.1.23-src/jni/native/
./configure --with-apr=/root/apr-1.5.2 --with-ssl=/usr/lib64/openssl --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.85.x86_64
make && make install
```

Create the $CATALINA_HOME/bin/setenv.sh file with following lines
`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH='$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/apr/lib'`

Configure in Server.xml for SSL

```
<Connector
       protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
       port="443" maxThreads="200"
       scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
       SSLCertificateFile="certicatefile" 
       SSLCertificateKeyFile="certificatekeyfile"
       SSLProtocol="TLSv1+TLSv1.1+TLSv1.2"/>
```